# Google map embedded link causes dangerous Request.Path error in mvc 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I save in database (Table.Field = Business.GoogleMap) links from GoogleMap like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=22,+Cholul,+Yucat%C3%A1n,+M%C3%A9xico&aq=0&sll=21.029046,-89.634623&sspn=0.024395,0.033045&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=22,+Cholul,+Yucat%C3%A1n,+Mexico&ll=21.040207,-89.558401&spn=0.048465,0.06609&z=14&iwloc=A
```

Then, in my View, I used it in this way:

```
<iframe width="940" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
src="@Html.Raw(Model.Business.GoogleMap)">
</iframe>
```

Then I get the error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path
>   value was detected from the client
>   (&).

I have tried the "Validation" fix, adding `[ValidateInput(false)]` to controller, and even adding `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` to the web.config, but error still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need to correctly encode the Google Map URL (or whatever it is that causes the Request.**Path** to be dangerous) when posting it to your controller.

It appears you can add `requestPathInvalidCharacters` attribute with an empty value to your `httpRuntime` section in web.config to allow those "invalid" characters to be in the url ([see here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/Offtopic/thread/f6205835-a89f-4664-93c9-da6a4dde0efb)). But I think correctly handling the URL in the first place would be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found the problem, error was only when the link was empty! when it actually has an url, it shows ok. Yes, that was stupid, sorry and thanks for your time.

Comment: @Nestor you can select this as the answer, you know.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue when using links such as Google Maps.  All you have to do is is apply `[AllowHtml]` above the Model trying to store/access that link/data.  So it would look something like this:

```
public class Locations
{
[AllowHtml]
public string Map_Link { get; set; }
}
```

But keep in mind that you are allowing a lot of other potentially dangerous attacks to occur by doing this.  So do some research before acting on this. I ended up not going this route personally, just because it made me nervous.